# How to load external js script from URL in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js server running on a VPS and I want to use a js script that is served from another server, something like:

```
http://example.com/api/js
```

How do I load this script and use it in my node.js file?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe download the script and then copy paste it into your file?

Otherwise check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481058/load-and-execute-external-js-file-in-node-js-with-access-to-local-variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec('wget http://example.com/api/js', function(stdout) {  });` should do the trick. If you need advanced control, use `http` module.