# Any way to include/require file in NodeJS like Python or PHP?

Tags: python, node.js, require

I defined many functions in a file called util.js, and I will take the function encode as an example. 
when using, it should be like this:

```
var util = require('./util.js');
util.encode();
```

but I want to use encode directly,just like using it in PHP or Python:

```
include "util.php"
encode();
```

Is there any way to achieve in NodeJS?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load and execute external js file in node.js with access to local variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481058/load-and-execute-external-js-file-in-node-js-with-access-to-local-variables)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in this way:

```
var encode = require('./util.js').encode;
encode();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//utils.js
decode = function(){
    console.log(222);
}
exports.wrap = function(g){
    g.encode = function(){}
}

//main.js
require('./utils.js').wrap(global);
encode();
decode();
```