# Include javascript file in node.js from external url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do you include/import JavaScript file(s) in node.js from an external URL?
I have tried `include("http://example.com/script.js");` which did not work. I have seen [Load and execute external js file in node.js with access to local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481058/load-and-execute-external-js-file-in-node-js-with-access-to-local-variables). However I want to include a script from another domain. 
I want to have something similar to this in HTML.

```
<script src="http://example.com/script.js"></script>
<script>
    //do stuff
</script>
```

I am using Express.js.

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't think it's possible. At least not using require(). I just looked at node's [module documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) and I didn't see anything suggesting it could be done. Maybe using http.request()? Then you'd still have to figure out how to load the module in the app.

Comment: I know i lead you unto another abandoned question, but as you will see the way to go is as Nocturno describes, http.get the source and eval.