# Run node script from within a node script

Tags: node.js, shell

I would like to use node-schedule to run a certain node script at a certain time. Can I do something like this in node.js?

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

//https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule
var j = schedule.scheduleJob('00 00 22 * * *', function () {
    console.log('Running XX node.js script ...');

    NodeShell.run(__dirname + '\\XX.js', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('finished');
    });
});
```

Not sure if something like `NodeShell` exists. Other alternatives would be welcomed.

Comment: There are a [bunch](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_asynchronous_process_creation) of ways to spawn processes in node.js.

Comment: If you dont want to create new processes using `child_process` module, `vm` is the way to go: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8808328/405398

Comment: why not just simply use require. running node script doesnot make sense however some bash or other script looks ok !!!

Comment: Why cant you just do this with a cronjob ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several options, all of which are listed in the [docs for `child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). Briefly:

- `child_process.exec` spawns a shell
- `child_process.fork` forks a node process
- `child_process.spawn` spawns a process

For your case, to run a node script you could use something like this:

```
var childProcess = require("child_process");
var path = require("path");
var cp = childProcess.fork(path.join(__dirname, "xx.js"));
cp.on("exit", function (code, signal) {
    console.log("Exited", {code: code, signal: signal});
});
cp.on("error", console.error.bind(console));
```