# Load an external javascript file as a node process

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3

I'm writing integration tests for purescript FFI bindings with [google's API map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

The problem Google's code is meant to be loaded externally with a `<script>` tag in browser not downloaded and run in a node process.  What I've got now will download the relevant file as `gmaps.js` but I don't know what to do to actually *run the file*.

```
exports.setupApiMap = function() {
  require('dotenv').config();
  const apiKey = process.env.MAPS_API_KEY;
  const gmaps = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + apiKey;
  require('download')(gmaps, "gmaps.js");
  // what now???
  return;
};
```

For my unit tests, I must later be able to run `new google.maps.Marker(...)`.  Then I can check that my `setTitle`, `getTitle` etc. bindings are working correctly.

Comment: Why you don't want to mock it?

Comment: might want to look up puppetteer for running browsers programatically.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ I'd like to run these test as a part of gitlab CI.  I don't think I can run a browser in gitlab CI.  But TBH I've never used browser mocking before.  It might be the best answer.

Comment: I meant mock marker object behaviour

Comment: Unit tests was the wrong description, these really are integration-tests.  The code I'm testing is just purescript FFI bindings, it doesn't really do anything but call external javascript.  I need to check that I've written them correctly against the canonical source.

Answer (score -2):

This is a duplicate question of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481058/load-and-execute-external-js-file-in-node-js-with-access-to-local-variables).  The correct code was.

```
exports.setupApiMap = async function() {
  require('dotenv').config();
  const apiKey = process.env.MAPS_API_KEY;
  const gmaps = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + apiKey;
  await require('download')(gmaps, __dirname);
  const google = require('./js');
  return;
};
```

The key was to download to `__dirname` before using require.  That said my specific use cases didn't work since google's API map code just can't be run in a node process.  It must be run in a browser.